# About start Widgets of Setting pacakge on sdk version7

Tags: android

I am do a app Launcher like   adw launcher,I run my app very well on the >2.1
but when <2.1 my app is run mistake.the mistake is :Long Press Screen,then appear Add to Home screen Dialog,when you choice Widget item,it appear null point.but on >2.2 all is Ok, my code is:

```
case AddAdapter.ITEM_APPWIDGET: {
            int appWidgetId =     Launcher.this.mAppWidgetHost.allocateAppWidgetId();

            Intent pickIntent = new Intent(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_PICK);

            pickIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
            // start the pick activity
            startActivityForResult(pickIntent, REQUEST_PICK_APPWIDGET);
            /*if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<8)
            {
                Log.I("aa","ddddd");
                Intent pickIntent = new Intent(); //AppWidgetPickActivity
                pickIntent.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.AppWidgetPickActivity");
                //pickIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);

                startActivityForResult(pickIntent, REQUEST_PICK_APPWIDGET);

            }*/
            break;
        }
```

my code is the same as adw launcher and  open source 2.2,I think,2.1 Setting is not the same as 2.2,can you tell me how to do we can compatible?